# Streaming BigQuery API

Tags: ruby, google-bigquery, google-api-client, google-api-ruby-client

According to Google [BigQuery Doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) it states.

> To help ensure data consistency, you can supply **insertId** for each
>   inserted row. BigQuery remembers this ID for at least one minute. If
>   you try to stream the same set of rows within that time period and the
>   insertId property is set, BigQuery uses the insertId property to
>   de-duplicate your data on a best effort basis.

Trying to implement the same using [Ruby client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/).I can't seemed to find a way to set the **insertID** in the stream request(reference attached [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/generated/google/apis/bigquery_v2/service.rb#L646-L659)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the insert_id in:
`Class: Google::Apis::BigqueryV2::InsertAllTableDataRequest::Row`

If you look at the `Row`  definition it's there [in the source](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/c530a350fc1a5bdb02b42c7a7c0dbc73d5b26dd5/generated/google/apis/bigquery_v2/classes.rb#L2096):

You can find more documention also on [RubyInfo](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/BigqueryV2/InsertAllTableDataRequest/Row)

Comment: I saw the earlier link but I guess the *RubyInfo* is something I missed. Thanks.